# How to transform a list of dataframes to an array of integer to perform CNN?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, conv-neural-network, reshape

I have a problem and I post here as I didn't find any solutions on the other topics.
I have a dataframe (X2df) of 525 rows and 533 columns. As I want to use each row to perform CNN, I splitted it by row using this : x_train = split(X2df, rownames(X2df)).
When I use view() function it displays this for the first rows : [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNWHA.png)

I believed that it was all good as every vector of the list is a dataframe but when I used dim() function for x_train[1] (or an other number), it results as NULL dimension.

As I want to perform CNN, I think that I need to have a list of matrix with 1,533,1 dimensions so I tried to use as.matrix and as.dataframe functions but it didn't change anything. Also, I tried to use array_reshape function like that :

img_rows = 1
img_cols = 533
for(i in 525)
{x_train[i] <- array_reshape(x_train[i], c(nrow(x_train[i]), img_rows, img_cols, 1))}

But it displays : "Error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,533,1)"

Thank you very much for your help !!!

Have a good day ;)